# 2 related comboboxes in wpf DataGrid MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

Does anyone have an example of binding a 2 related ComboBoxs to a Selected Item of a DataGrid? I have tried, but I can't seem to get it to work. I am fairly new to MVVM so I am doing something wrong.

I have a datagrid which is binded to a collection in an object named `NewClient` in my ViewModel
`ClientMarketCodes`. 
`ClientMarketCodes` has a navigation property named `MarketCodeTypes` which has a Market Navigation property. so I want to show in the datagrid the code,`MarketCodeTyeName`,`MarketName`.
I have Managed to show `Markets` and `MarketCodeTypes` in DataGrid comboboxes, but I want to do a relation between `Markets` and `MaketCodeTypes` where user can only select `MarketCodeTypes` related to there `Market`.
I have added a selected item to `Markets` Combobox where on changing it excute filling method of `MarketCodeTypes` collection binded to `MarketCodeTypes` Combobox but it doesnt work correctly as the filter applys to all rows of `MarketCodetypes` Combobox column. 
I have something that happens in both combobox for example on changing the `Markets` of one row the combobox shows all other markets I choosed one other Market and click the row is not affected and returns back to its original Market.i dont know why this happens.

Heres my ViewModel:

```
public class MarketsViewModel : ObservableObject, IMarketsViewModel, INavigationAware, IConfirmNavigationRequest, IRegionMemberLifetime
{
    #region MarketsViewModel

    public MarketsViewModel()
    {
        //NewClient.ClientMarketCodes[0].MarketCodeType.MarketID
        //MarketCodeTypes = new ObservableCollection<MarketCodeType>();
        this.GetMarkets();
        //this.GetMarketCodeTypes();
        this.PropertyChanged += MarketssViewModel_PropertyChanged;
    }

    private void MarketssViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.PropertyName)
        {
            case "selectedMarket":
            {
                if (selectedMarket != null)
                {
                    GetMarketCodeTypes();
                }

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region --Members--

    private ObservableCollection<Market> m_Market;
    private ObservableCollection<MarketCodeType> m_MarketCodeType;
    private List<MarketCodeType> m_MarketCodeTypes;

    public List<MarketCodeType> MarketCodeTypesList
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_MarketCodeTypes == null)
            {
                m_MarketCodeTypes = new List<MarketCodeType>();
            }

            return m_MarketCodeTypes;
        }
        set
        { 
            m_MarketCodeTypes = value;

            RaisePropertyChanged("MarketCodeTypesList");
            RaisePropertyChanged("MarketCodeTypes");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MarketCodeType> MarketCodeTypes
    {
        get
        {
            if (MarketCodeTypesList != null)
                return new ObservableCollection<MarketCodeType>(MarketCodeTypesList);
            else
                return new ObservableCollection<MarketCodeType>();
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region --Properties--

    public ObservableCollection<Market> Markets
    {
        get { return m_Market; }
        set
        {
            m_Market = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Markets");
        }
    }

    private Market _selectedMarket;
    public Market selectedMarket
    {
        get { return _selectedMarket; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedMarket != value)
            {
                _selectedMarket = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("selectedMarket");
                RaisePropertyChanged("MarketCodeTypes");
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    private void GetMarkets()
    {
        try
        {
            Market[] MarketArr;

            using (var client = new ClientServiceProxy())
            {
                MarketArr = client.GetAllMarkets();
            }
            if (MarketArr != null)
            {
                this.Markets = new ObservableCollection<Market>(MarketArr);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
    }

    private void GetMarketCodeTypes()
    {
        try
        {
            MarketCodeType[] MarketCodeTypeArr;
            using (var client = new ClientServiceProxy())
            {
                MarketCodeTypeArr = client.GetAllMarketCodeTypes().Where(c=>c.MarketID==selectedMarket.marketID).ToArray();
            }
            if (MarketCodeTypeArr != null)
            {
                MarketCodeTypesList = MarketCodeTypeArr.ToList();
            }
            else
            { MarketCodeTypesList = new List<MarketCodeType>(); }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
    }
}`
```

Here's My Xaml:

```
 <Grid x:Name="grid2" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">

        <Custom:C1DataGrid x:Name="c1DataGrid"  
                           AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                           Height="490"  
                           ItemsSource="{Binding Path=NewClient.ClientMarketCodes,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,ValidatesOnExceptions=True}">
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFBEBE00" Offset="0.5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFEDED9A" Offset="0.496"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Custom:C1DataGrid.HeaderBackground>
            <Custom:C1DataGrid.Columns>
                <!--<Custom:DataGridCheckBoxColumn  Header="???? ?????"/>-->
                <Custom:DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Binding="{Binding Code,Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="False"  />

                <Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="MarketCodeType" >
                    <Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MarketCodeType.NameA}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                          <ComboBox  Name="cmbMarketCodeTypes" 
                                                 ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=my:MarketsView},Path=DataContext.MarketCodeTypes}" 
                                                 DisplayMemberPath="NameA" 
                                                 SelectedValue="{Binding Path=MarketCodeTypeID,Mode=TwoWay,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
                                                />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                </Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Markets">
                    <Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MarketCodeType.Market.NameA}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox Name="cmbMarkets" ItemsSource= "{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=my:MarketsView},Path=DataContext.Markets,Mode=TwoWay}" 
  DisplayMemberPath="NameA" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=MarketCodeType.Market.MarketID,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                SelectedValuePath="MarketCodeType.MarketID"
       SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=my:MarketsView},Path=DataContext.selectedMarket,Mode=TwoWay}"    />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                </Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn> 


                </Custom:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </Custom:C1DataGrid.Columns>

        </Custom:C1DataGrid>
```

Comment: I would recommend to use converter as I have described here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463243/add-datagrid-checkboxcolumn-with-different-values-in-different-rows/18463844#18463844

Comment: thanks i will c i,but i need to knw y i cant update any combobox columns after selecting an item from the combobox it returns back to its original value.example the first row  the Market is set to KSA i selected to edit the market the combobox shows and i selected USA but it dont change and returns back to KSA!